# Making transitionX animation with frame by frame animation cause lags

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, kotlin

I have an ImageView. When user presses a button I want my view to set an image from R.drawable(every time image is different) and then do `translationX` animation with frame-by-frame animation. For this purpose, I use `ObjectAnimtor.OfFloat(..."translationX"...)` and in `doOnStart` I call `AnimationDrawable.start()` on my image( I set animation-list there). Actually, on `doOnEnd` I put in my View another image (animation-list) and start another animation. After that, I make my image invisible and return it to the start point using `translationX`. Testing it on real device and on emulator causes lags at the start of the animation and in the moment when I change image. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
view.setImageResource(
            this.resources.getIdentifier(
                "${spellCasted}_anim",
                "drawable", context!!.packageName
            )
        )
        val x1 = startXposition
        val x2 = firstXdestination
        val frameAnimation = view.drawable as AnimationDrawable
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                view,
                "translationX",
                x1.toFloat(),
                x2.toFloat()
            ).apply {
                duration = 900
                interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
                doOnStart {
                    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    frameAnimation.start()
                }
                doOnEnd {
                    if (hasPost(splitSpell)) { //hasPost(..) check is there additional image to translate from x2 to x2 + 20
                        frameAnimation.stop()
                        view.setImageResource(
                            context!!.resources.getIdentifier(
                                "${spellCasted}stop_anim",
                                "drawable", context!!.packageName
                            )
                        )
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                                view, "translationX",
                                x2.toFloat(),
                                x2.toFloat() +  20f
                            )
                                .apply {
                                    duration = 1200
                                    interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
                                    doOnStart {
                                        val frameAnimationStop =
                                            view.drawable as AnimationDrawable
                                        frameAnimationStop.start()
                                    }
                                    doOnEnd {
                                        setDefault(view, x1, isEnemy) //returns view to startPos
                                    }
                                    start()
                                }
                    } else {
                        setDefault(view, x1, isEnemy)//returns view to startPos
                    }
                }
                start()
            }
```

Comment: How frequently does the image change? Are you changing as it continues to move to its destination X position? It would really help to see your code to know how to adapt it to avoid the hiccups.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you your answer, I'v added this anim function so now you can check.

Comment: @Tenfour04 there are about 5 - 9 frames in every animation list that I set to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the javadoc for `imageView.setImageResource`, you'll see it says it will cause a latency hiccup because it loads the image on the UI thread.

I think you can fix this by pre-loading your next drawable in the background. I haven't tried this because I don't work with animation drawables, so sorry in advance if it doesn't cure the hiccups.

Coroutines will make this a lot easier to set up and keep orderly. You can start by creating a function that eliminates the need for nested Animator callbacks:

```
suspend fun Animator.runToCompletion(): Unit = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    doOnEnd { cont.resume(Unit) }
    start()
}
```

Then when you start the animation, you can start loading the next drawable in the background, and hopefully it will be ready by the time you need to show it:

```
val cxt = requireContext() // one source of failure if context is null

lifecycleScope.launch {

    // Start loading the second animation in a background thread
    val spellStopAnimationJob: Deferred<AnimationDrawable> = async(Dispatchers.Default) {
        cxt.getDrawable(ctx.resources.getIdentifier(
            "${spellCasted}stop_anim",
            "drawable", ctx.packageName
        ) as AnimationDrawable
    }

    view.setImageResource(
       resources.getIdentifier(
                "${spellCasted}_anim",
                "drawable", cxt.packageName
            )
    )
    val x1 = startXposition
    val x2 = firstXdestination
    val initialAnimation = view.drawable as AnimationDrawable
        .apply { start() }
    view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
        view,
        "translationX",
        x1.toFloat(),
        x2.toFloat()
    ).apply {
        duration = 900L
        interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    }.runToCompletion()

    if (hasPost(splitSpell)) { //hasPost(..) check is there additional image to translate from x2 to x2 + 20
        initialAnimation.stop()

        // Wait for the animation to be loaded (hopefully it's already done so no hiccup)
        val stopAnimation = spellStopAnimationJob.await()
            .apply { start() }
        view.setImageDrawable(stopAnimation)
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            view, "translationX",
            x2.toFloat(),
            x2.toFloat() + 20f
        ).apply {
            duration = 1200
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        }.runToCompletion()
    }

    setDefault(view, x1, isEnemy)//returns view to startPos
}
```

By the way that line `x2.toFloat() + 20f` is going to mess you up when you run this on different devices, since you're hard-coding an offset in pixels instead of DIP units. You should specify the number in DIP units and multiply by `resources.displayMetrics.density` to convert it to pixel units.

Comment: Thank you very much! I read docs and you are totally right! I have an idea. May be I can preload Resouyces into Drawable(s) and just use it? Docks say that setImageDrawable doesn't stop UI.

Comment: Maybe. You just need to be careful about not going over the allotted heap memory if the images are large or there are a lot of them. Android is very stingy with heap memory. If you're making a game that has very many images, you should consider OpenGL (or a game engine) so the images are loaded to GPU memory as textures. There is of course a memory limit for the GPU as well, but it is significantly higher.